# How to declare a std::map with enum as key and functions with varying signatures as values?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, enums, stdmap

*I suppose this is a very simple question to advanced C++ programmers, but I'm not one, so:*

Using C++ 11, what's an elegant way to implement a `std::map` that uses a scoped `enum` as a key and takes mathematical functions that have varying signatures as values:

Simple example - could be any numeric type or any number of function args, but these are typical for my use case:

```
enum class FUNCS
    {
         DOUBLE_FUNC1, DOUBLE_FUNC2, INT_FUNC3, INT_FUNC4
    };
```

Some functions:

```
double f1( int a, int b, double d);
double f2( int a, int b, int c, int d);
int f3( int a, double d, int c, double e);
int f4( int a, double d, int c);
```

The functionality I seek is a std::map that works like this:

Initialize the map:

```
mMAP[FUNCS::DOUBLE_FUNC1]=f1;
mMAP[FUNCS::DOUBLE_FUNC2]=f2;
mMAP[FUNCS::INT_FUNC3]=f3;
mMAP[FUNCS::INT_FUNC4]=f4;
```

Use the map:

```
mMAP[FUNCS::DOUBLE_FUNC1](a,b,d);
mMAP[FUNCS::INT_FUNC3](a,d,c,e);
```

***A compromise that would involve some type casting could use functions with varying arguments that all return `double`:***

```
double f1( int a, int b, double d);
double f2( int a, int b, int c, int d);
double f3( int a, double d, int c, double e);
double f4( int a, double d, int c);
```

How can I can declare a map that will give me this functionality? I understand that I probably cannot map those functions directly to those keys - I will need some sort of abstraction/indirection to accomplish this goal, and I believe that using variadic functions/templates this can be accomplished, see [**Variadic arguments**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments) and [**Parameter pack**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack), but I'm really not clear on how to do get this working.

Meanwhile I have implemented a cludgy solution using a function pointer type that takes a `std::tuple` containing a series of values of all possible types as an argument with references for the results, and then in each fuction mapped, I use the appropriate members of the tuple. **UGLY!**

*My goal here is to send data from these various functions to a charting library which generates charts using data of type `boost::any` A GUI driven state machine will call the appropriate function through the map based on the enum value represented in the state machine, and generate a chart based on data from that function.*

Comment: Does each `FUNCS` value correspond to a single, unique function type?

Comment: @T.C. - No. If they did, there would be no question! Please read. :)

Comment: In other words, you want to also be able to write `mMAP[FUNCS::DOUBLE_FUNC1] = f2;`?

Comment: @T.C. - basically, yes although that's not the point. The point is to have a uniform, succint, symmetrical interface for mapping these various functions without all sorts of conditional logic. Please read the question carefully - I believe it is quite clear. Correct me if I'm wrong. Sorry.

Comment: How is the programmer or the compiler to know which argument signature to use?

Comment: @Unapiedra - that's what the map does.

Comment: Down-voter - please explain. Unexplained down-votes are not very constructive.

Comment: @Vector, no the map does not tell anything about the signature. At least not as you have it presented at the moment. You've created an enum but you'd need an additional mapping of enum to signature.

Comment: @Unapiedra - understood. I misspoke - the point is there needs to be an abstraction of some sort that is parameter agnostic, that the map can use appropriately.

Comment: If your only problem is keeping the data in the map, why not just store it in `boost::any`?

Comment: @DanielKO - I don't like to use `boost::any` in my code.

Comment: `boost::any` will guarantee you are casting it back to the right type. It looks like you are designing something so abstract that it should only be responsible for passing the data around between the producer and the consumer. This the perfect job for `boost::any`.

Comment: @DanielKO - I see. I thought it worked simply like a variant type - perhaps this is something to look into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ is a statically typed language.

The only way you could do this would be to have all the functions use a common signature, for instance:

```
struct F1Data { double result; int a; int b; double d; };
struct F2Data { double result; int a, b, c, d; };
struct F3Data { int result; int a, b; double c; };
struct F4Data { int result; double a, b; int c; };

void f1(void* data);
void f2(void* data);
void f3(void* data);
void f4(void* data);
```

Then within each the functions, you can cast `data` to the right type and work on the values from there.

That's as close as you'll be able to get. You can mask it with libraries like `tuple` or `any` but it will always boil down to making a shared signature across all of the functions.

Comment: How about with [**Variadic arguments**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments) and/or [**Parameter pack**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)?

Comment: Variadic arguments would do it, but is less clean by far than my suggestion. Parameter packs will affect the function's type and are also going to be more difficult to work with.

Comment: I'm probably just going use a switch, but all things considered this probably the simplest, cleanest way to accomplish what I am looking for, so I'm accepting this answer.

Comment: Thanks! I agree, go with the switch. It's more natural.

Answer (score 1):

Since all functions have different signatures, it is not possible.

Since all functions have different types, you can't even use some kind of type erasure.

Comment: It can only be done via compromises that collapse all the argument types into one hybrid type. C++ is a statically typed language.

Comment: I am not convinced this is impossible. See edit: [**Variadic arguments**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments) and [**Parameter pack**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)

Comment: @Vector You are better with redesigning then trying to use variadic arguments. Actually, as said [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27386465/476681), you can use type erasure, but then you need to put the return value to the structure.

Comment: @BЈовић - never really worked with variadic arguments, and they don't look pretty; casting `void*`  is just not a good design option IMO, although it would be easier to manage than the cludgy `tuple` approach, which is very ugly. I'm beginning to think I should just forget the map and use `switch` .

Comment: Yes, use a switch. If you can avoid this battle, then do so.